# Calculate center of mass for parameter equations

Tags: integration

I need to calculate the center of mass for G, where G = {$y=0$, $x = a(t - sint)$, $y = a(1-cost)$ | $t \in [0; 2\pi]$}.

I know that $x_c = \int_G{\int{xdxdy}}$ but the problem that $x$ and $y$ in parameter equation. There is a need for a variable replacement but I can't come up with something.

I tried to find some examples in books but there is no example with parameter equations. I just need an idea for a variable replacement.

Comment: There is some mistake in the equation of $G$.

Comment: Why do you think that?

Comment: Your $G$ is just a single point.

Comment: Yes. Sorry about that. y = 0

Comment: Hint: $x(t) = a(t - sint)$ so $x(0) = a(0 - sin(0)), x(2\pi) = a(2\pi - sin(2\pi))$ What can you do about the bounds of the integral knowing this?

Comment: x from $0$ to $2a\pi$, y from $0$ to $2a$